# How to properly generate html reports with Jenkins?

Tags: matlab, jenkins

I'm using Jenkins to generate HTML reports with Matlab and it almost works.
To view the HTML output I need to

1) download it and open with Firefox or IE

or

2) open it directly from Jenkins with IE.

But if I open it directly from Jenkins with Firefox, the HTML looks crappy. Images are missing etc. I'm not sure where the real problem is, Jenkins/Firefox/Matlab? I have the HTML publisher plugin on my Jenkins but I am not using it, at least not explicitly. HTML is purely Matlab output. Any idea how to make the HTML accessible from Jenkins on Firefox?

Comment: Could you add a sample of the generated HTML? In Jenkins your HTML should be able to fit into a <div> tag. No Header, no Body. Also, if your HTML is not well generated, your browser will compensate as much as possible.